# Laravel 8 route login not defined

Tags: laravel

I'm having some issues with authentication middleware in Laravel 8. At present, when I run my tests I get the error `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined`.

I've installed `jetstream` and `livewire` and can see these in my `routes` folder. My test should be redirecting to `login` as there is no user logged in. I am assuming this is an issue with the `middleware('auth')` not going where it needs to, but I can't find any information on how to solve it.

This is my test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\Project;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ProjectsTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithFaker, RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function only_authenticated_users_can_create_projects()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $attributes = Project::factory()->raw();
        $this->post('/projects', $attributes)->assertRedirect('login');
    }
}
```

Routes

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
 */

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectsController@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/projects/{project}', 'ProjectsController@show');
Route::post('/projects', 'ProjectsController@store')->middleware('auth');


Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

ProjectsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Project;
use App\Models\User;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        //Return all projects. Compact creates an array made up of both variables and values.
        $projects = auth()->user()->projects;
        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
    }

    public function show(Project $project)
    {
        //Get the wildcard no passed in as a reference and search for it in Project. If it doesn't exist, fail.
        return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
    }

    public function store()
    {
        //validate - check for title/description
        $attributes = request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);
        //Use middleware to check owner is logged in and then pass in project
        auth()->user()->projects()->create($attributes);
        //redirect - return a new view
        return redirect('/projects');
    }
}
```

Comment: `php artisan route:list` and see if there is a route named 'login'

Comment: I can't see a login route - in the tutorial I'm following there isn't one defined, I think it's defined somewhere in the middleware?

Comment: if there isn't one in the route list then there isn't one in your application ... sounds like one of these crazy service providers for this joke of a thing called jetstream and fortify might not be running

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue using livewire and fortify. The solution is to have a named login route

```
Route::get('login', \App\Http\Livewire\Login::class)->name('login');
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue recently. Solve it after reading the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Check if the route is valid and included:

```
$ php artisan route:list
```

Then

```
$ php artisan route:cache
```